# can we use cassandra / couchdb / mongodb with google app engine infrastructure?

Tags: google-app-engine, mongodb, couchdb, cassandra

Is there anyway we can use Google App Engine but do not use google's bigtable?

Like for storing my data, I would prefer to use  cassandra and have the ability to plug and unplug additional database servers.

And say if I would like to use CouchDb/MongoDb instead  is it supported in the GAE's infrastructure?

Comment: I really don't see how you could do that... GAE is tightly linked to Google products!

Comment: semantics-note: GAE doesn't use BigTable directly. It uses the *Datastore* which is built on *Megastore* which is built on *BigTable*.

Comment: @Chris provide a link to that claim

Comment: @houyi: [this post](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2009/09/migration-to-better-datastore.html) gives a good outline of the changes that took place in 2009. I believe the [more 9's talk](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=video&cd=1&ved=0CDMQtwIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DxO015C3R6dw&ei=kYUdTsrdDIv4sgbhhqiyDQ&usg=AFQjCNFaZNkkoMcKe4XCKcexhf6n-MQZug&sig2=1eougR9CqmfSn29-xSR-IA) briefly touches on the platform layers

Comment: Why would you want to do this? One of the major advantages of App Engine is that it provides an integrated, scalable datastore.

Comment: If you want MongoDB-like API you may want to try: https://github.com/mungo-appengine/mungo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short answer**: No.

**Longer answer**: It depends how you want/need to use the database systems. There is no way you could run those system directly on AppEngine. But if low-latency was not a prerequisite  (as would be the case with infrequent/periodical fetches of data) then you could set them up on another host with some kind of HTTP API, and query your services from appengine using `urlfetch`.

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents:

I dont think you can do what you want on Google App Engine directly. If you really need other databases, then Amazon's EC2 may e what you are looking for.

Also, Take a look at this: [Using Quercus® to Run the WordPress PHP blog on Google App Engine](http://www.caucho.com/articles/Quercus_on_GAE.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Cassandra database on Google App Engine but in its [flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/). But, as of now, flexible environment is in Beta version and is not recommended for production use.