# Can Cassandra be used with Google App Engine application?

Tags: google-app-engine, cassandra

I want to use Cassandra database with a GAE application.

I tried DataStax Java driver and the following exception comes while connecting to the database:

```
    access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")
```

Any suggestions as to how to resolve this Exception?

The answers to the question in  the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676692/can-we-use-cassandra-couchdb-mongodb-with-google-app-engine-infrastructure) says it is not possible to use Cassandra directly.

Is it possible to use Cassandra directly with GAE? Is there any other driver or workaround which can support Cassandra on GAE?

Comment: I believe you can use it from ManagedVM

Comment: Thanks. Cassandra works with Managed VM.